# CDN Datatables serverside. Send extra parameters not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables-1.10

I try to send extra paramater but it doesnot work. Can somebody help me please?

```
var t = $('#userTable').DataTable( {
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxTestTable",
            "data": function ( d ) {
                d.myKey = "myValue";
            },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "totalUser" },        
                { "data": "fullname" },
                { "data": "username" },
                { "data": "ministryid" },
                { "data": "gradeid" },
                { "data": "officeemail" }
            ],
            "columnDefs": [ {
                "searchable": false,
                "orderable": false,
                "targets": 0
            } ],
            "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
        } );
```

I try to open browser console and it said:

"TypeError: data is undefined"
if ( data.DT_RowId ) {

If i remove "data: function" it will work fine.Why i cant send extra parameter?

Comment: data should be a object not a function from what i remember

Comment: @madalinivascu what do you mean by that? Can you show some example? I also try use "data": {"user_id": 451 } . It show no error but when i try to check sent parameter it show nothing.

Comment: `{user_id: 451 }` where are you trying to check the parameter?

Comment: @madalinivascu i check at ajax parameter sent at browser developer console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax property is a object:

```
    $('#example').dataTable( {
      "ajax": {
        "url":"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajaxTestTable",
        "data": function ( d ) {
            d.user_id= 451 ;
         }
       }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for ur answer. I wrongly put data outside ajax..hehehe